# Disable Sorting in Datagridview

Tags: datagridview, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi I have a Datagridview i want to make that grid not sortable when the user clicks on column name.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Through the property of the `DataGridView`. Go to edit columns and change the SortMode option to NotSortable.
2. Through code. Write this for each column you want to disable sorting.

   ```
   dataGridView1.Columns[ColumnNumber].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
   ```